# Divide Datagrid into 2 parts

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid which is showing around 20 products.
Now i want to divide this grid in to 2 parts such that part one will contain products that are currently available with header "Availabe products" and part two will contain sold out products with header "Sold out products". Both Grid will have to be shown by a common scrollbar.
I can acheive this with 2 different datagrids but i am looking for a solution in which i don't have to divide my products in to two lists.

Comment: Do not split them into two list, but have two LINQ queries over the same data source: Source.Where(i => i.Sold) and Source.Where(i => i.Available)

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you use a Group with ObservableCollection.